# safari input type='number' can't display real value

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var p = document.querySelector('p');

input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  p.innerHTML = e.target.value;
  // e.target.value = e.target.value;
})
```

```html
<input type="number" />
<p></p>
```

if you input 123$, the e.target.value === '' in event callback, but the input render '123$' on screen; Why is there a difference in safari? if uncomment, can make the two equal. Is this a bug?

Comment: In the commented out line, you're trying to assign an invalid value, so it just quits and calls it an empty string.

Comment: @jhpratt i know '123$' is invalid value, but why the input render '123$' on screen and e.target.value === '' in input event callback.

Comment: Because you're not assigning it there. You're getting the value, which was input _by the user_ to be invalid. I don't know what the spec says, but it certainly makes sense that you can't assign a value (the commented line) that's invalid.

Comment: sorry, i haven't understand; e.target.value = e.target.value works like this;
if input '1' first, e.target.value = '1', then input 'a', e.target.value = ''; the empty string is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to make the `<p>` element display whatever is in the `<input>` tag, but some things aren't displaying correctly. This is because you have a `number` type `<input>` tag, and `123$` is defined as a string by JavaScript. Try changing the `type` attribute to `name` and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: the code result is different in Chrome and Safari. I don't understand the cause of result in Safari

Comment: You may want to check compatibility between browsers.